# Include job listing details with application confirmation email

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

Please include a copy of job posting within the e-mail "Success! Your application was sent". I've applied 2 weeks ago. The company deleted their job description and now I can't see it from my outgoing messages on Stack Overflow Jobs (it just says "Job is no longer available").

Comment: I think that's a good suggestion. Including the content of the job listing in the confirmation email would be one option. Another possibility would be to allow applicants to see the job listing even after it has expired

Answer (score 10):

For your current application, please [contact our support team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) - they'll be able to help you out. Make sure to select "I need help with Stack Overflow Jobs" from the dropdown.

Improving the post-application candidate UX is on our list of future improvements and this is very valuable feedback, so thank you for that!

Honestly though, I'm not sure if including the entire job listing in the confirmation email is the best option here.

Personally, I'd much rather have a perpetual link next to every application on [Messages => Sent => Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/sent/applications). Right now - as you're pointing out - that link will no longer work as soon as the job listing has been taken down by its owner, so "Job is no longer available" is displayed instead. I think the right fix here is to let applicants see all job listings they've applied to, including listings which are no longer accessible to the general public.

Comment: I use my mailbox heavily to track progress of my applications, that's why I suggested that. It's more reliable in case StackOverflow Careers team changes something in the future. It's also the case if a company **changes** their job posting, because the e-mail that sent the moment you apply won't be altered. Having full job description at the very bottom of "Success" e-mail (or as an attachment) would be great! That also helps to keep all applications in one place (email box), because not all companies support "Easy Apply" feature on StackOverflow Careers.

Comment: Job listings *usually* don't get edited much, but valid point!

Comment: By the way, since you keep referring to "Stack Overflow Careers" - we've rebranded our jobs site to "Stack Overflow Jobs" several years ago. Do you still see the "Careers" branding anywhere on the site or in email notifications? If yes that would be a bug.

Comment: I've just used to start my searches with typing careers.stackoverflow.com in the address bar, that's why I was referring to it. I'll let you know if I find other mentions.